# Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll in visual studio

Tags: dll

I am using Visual Studio and dotnet version 4.6.1. My code is accepting data from Azure Event Hub. The code was working fine and it was receiving data from event hub but now I am getting multiple exceptions related to . I didn't make any changes in code. Yes, there is probability of setting changes in browsers. I am getting following exceptions. Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks in advance!

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x3898 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0xe54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x3fcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x2648 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x2e94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4564 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x3f20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpException' in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x10d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4738 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0xf10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x4584 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x3d58 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
```